# Null Handling in Oracle Based on Row Level Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where if the phone number is null for address type 'S', then we have to use the phone number of address type 'H'.

For Example :

| FULL_NM | EMAIL_ADDR | PH_NO | ADDR_TYPE | EEP_AGENT_NUMBER | EEP_AGENT_COMPANY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karthik | cmkarthik22@gmail.com | null | S | 117729 | INT |
| Karthik | cmkarthik22@gmail.com | 000-123-4567 | H | 117729 | INT |

We require the phone Number of H , if the phone number is null for address type 'S'

**The current Sql logic is as shown below :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TRIM(TRIM(TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_FIRST_NAME)
     || ' '
     || TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_MIDDLE_NAME) )
     || ' '
     || TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_LAST_NAME) ) AS FULL_NM,
    TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDR) AS EMAIL_ADDR,
    TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER) AS PH_NO,
    TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) AS ADDR_TYPE,
    TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER) AS EEP_AGENT_NUMBER,
    TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY) AS EEP_AGENT_COMPANY
FROM
    EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_AGENT A
    INNER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_CONTACT C ON
        A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER = C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_NUMBER
    AND
        A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY = C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_COMPANY
ORDER BY
    TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER),
    TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY),
    TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) DESC--- ORDER BY EEP_AGENT_NUMBER,EEP_AGENT_COMPANY,FULL_NM,EMAIL_ADDR,PH_NO,ADDR_TYPE
```

Can Any one please let me know on how this can be achieved ?

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k I tried using this Case statement and it not working as Desired CASE
     WHEN
                TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) = 'S'
            AND
                TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL
            THEN TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER)
            WHEN
                TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) = 'H'
            AND
                TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL
            THEN TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER)
            ELSE TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER)
        END
    AS PH_NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this:

You could simply join the table on itself, showing both S and H phone numbers on the same row, and using `NVL` to distinguish between them.

[NVL](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-nvl/) is essentially an if/then/else function for "If the first value is NULL, use the second value"

Pseudo query, may need to be tweaked to work with your data:

```
SELECT A.FULL_NM, S.PH_NO AS S_PH_NO, H.PH_NO AS H_PH_NO, NVL(S.PH_NO, H.PH_NO) AS PH_NO
FROM
    EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_AGENT A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_CONTACT S ON (A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER = S.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_NUMBER AND A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY = S.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_COMPANY AND ADDR_TYPE = 'S')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_CONTACT H ON (A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER = H.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_NUMBER AND A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY = H.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_COMPANY AND ADDR_TYPE = 'H')
```

As mentioned in the comments, using a CASE statement should also work, provided the data tables can be joined so all data for a single agent is returned in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and a `CASE` expression to give priority to the rows:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_FIRST_NAME)
         || ' '
         || TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_MIDDLE_NAME)
         || ' '
         || TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_LAST_NAME) AS FULL_NM,
         TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDR) AS EMAIL_ADDR,
         TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER) AS PH_NO,
         TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) AS ADDR_TYPE,
         TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER) AS EEP_AGENT_NUMBER,
         TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY) AS EEP_AGENT_COMPANY,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY
             TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY),
             TRIM(A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER)
           ORDER BY
             CASE
             WHEN TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL
             AND  TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) = 'S'
             THEN 1
             WHEN TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER) IS NOT NULL
             AND  TRIM(C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_ADDR_TYPE) = 'H'
             THEN 2
             ELSE 3
             END
         ) AS rn
  FROM   EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_AGENT A
         INNER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_PRD4_CONTACT C
         ON  A.EEP_AGENT_NUMBER = C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_NUMBER
         AND A.EEP_AGENT_COMPANY = C.EEP_AGENT_CONTACT_COMPANY
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY
       EEP_AGENT_NUMBER,
       EEP_AGENT_COMPANY
```

*Note: Do you really need to `TRIM` everything? Surely it would be better to do that once when you `INSERT` the data and not every time you `SELECT` the data?*

Comment: @ Thanks for your inputs , regarding the TRIM , These Data are loaded from Source through ETL systems and it will be fixed in the ETL side .  We just had a added requirement where EMAIL_ADDR Column should also be addressed the same way , Can this be Done in a Single Query ?

Comment: @karthik I've given you a single query. It only `SELECT`s from the table(s) once and the outer `SELECT` is an in-line view that merely filters the data.

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong about trimming the data each time. Sure, it would be better to not run all those extra steps, but when you are using an ETL, or some other tool outside your main app, this is better than having the app break. (On the other hand, if something is breaking because of extra white-space, it may also be good to track that down and fix it.)